# How to correct relation "auth_user" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_super

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x

I am using postgresql as my database and using email instead of username to authenticate. However each time I attempt to register a new user I get this :

> relation "auth_user" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "auth_user"
>   ("password", "last_login", "is_super...

This is my code on [Github](https://github.com/iivri/Nesting)

These is the response when I created the database :

[image]

These is the response when I ran the migrations :

[image]

If you have time and interest I would love to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try migrating `auth` explicitly: `python manage.py migrate auth`

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov This is what I got : (NestingSet) eloiim:Identity `iivri.andre$ python3 manage.py migrate auth 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: auth
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Answer (score 0):

In the `CreateAccountForm` you are importing the standard auth User model. You should be using your custom User model instead.